# HtttpWebRequest returns result of a request in another thread (Monotouch)

Tags: c#, multithreading, xamarin.ios, httpwebrequest

*This question is about Monotouch, but it could be a general .NET issue or an issue with the Mono library.*

I am experiencing the weirdest problem I have seen in a very long time.

I launch 2 threads, where each thread creates a HttpWebRequest. These threads are started at the same time (well, one millisecond apart). What happens is that the call to GetResponse() from the first HTTP request (url1) receives the contents of the second HTTP request (url2). When this happens, the second HTTP request times out after 30 seconds.

This doesn't happen every time, but it does happen 4 out of 5 times.

This is the code: (simplified to produce a working test case)

```
public void Launch()
{
   Thread thread1 = new Thread(() => { GetData("http://url1"); });
   Thread thread2 = new Thread(() => { GetData("http://url2"); });

   thread1.Start();
   thread2.Start();
}

public static void GetData(string url)
{
   try
   {
      XDocument xDoc;

      var webRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(url);

      using (var response = webRequest.GetResponse())
      {
         using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
         {
             xDoc = XDocument.Load(stream);

             Logger.Default.Log("Result for {0}: {1}", url, xDoc);
         }
      }
   }
   catch(Exception ex)
   {
       Logger.Default.Log("Result for {0}: [Exception: {1}]", url, ex.Message);
   }
}
```

This is the output (4 out of 5 times):

```
Result for http://url1: <contents of http://url2>
Result for http://url2: [Exception: timeout...]
```

When everything is ok (1 out of 5 times):

```
Result for http://url1: <contents of http://url1>
Result for http://url2: <contents of http://url2>
```

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't sound like general .net behaviour.

Sounds like a bug - report it to bugzilla at xamarin? https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/

Comment: Top job. Please do report back here when you get an answer or fix!

Comment: Good job - hopefully will get bumped up from "Normal" priority - as it sounds nasty!